# A question about Hahn-Banach theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis

Hahn-Banach theorem states:

> Let $X$ be a real vector space and $p$ a sublinear functional on it. Also, let $Z\subset X$ be a subspace, and $f$ a sublinear functional on $Z$. Also, for all $z\in Z$, $f(z)\leq p(z)$. Then $f$ has an extension, namely $\overline{f}$, such that $f(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Will this condition not be satisfied if I assign $f(x)=p(x)$ for all $x\in X\setminus Z$? Clearly:

1. $f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)$
2. $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$ for $\alpha\geq 0$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

$f$ is a *linear* functional and can be extended by a *linear* $p$-dominated $F$.